# Aligning an image next to a table using only HTML

Tags: html, css, tabular

I am working on designing a 'Hall of Fame' on my company's internal wiki.

The website is set up such that I have three images across the top (a trophy, a centered header image, another trophy) and a centered table beneath that.

I have a very tall image that says 'Hall of Fame' sideways that I would like to put along the side of the page.

How would I go about doing that? It appears that the editor on this wiki will only let you change the HTML so it seems that using div's and CSS to style the page is out of the question (correct me if I'm wrong). I'll link the HTML but it's a bit messy.

Thanks!

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img align="left" height="342" lconnwikimacro="image" lconnwikiparamattachmentname="trophy.png" lconnwikiparamwikipage="Hall of Fame" src="wikipage" style="height: 141px; width: 116px; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 65px" width="330" /> <img lconnwikimacro="image" lconnwikiparamattachmentname="SG_HoF_Pic2.png" lconnwikiparamwikipage="Hall of Fame" src="wikipage" /></a> <img align="right" height="342" lconnwikimacro="image" lconnwikiparamattachmentname="trophy.png" lconnwikiparamwikipage="Hall of Fame" src="wikipage" style="height: 141px; width: 116px; padding-top: 30px; padding-right: 65px" width="330" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center">
    &nbsp;</p>
<table>
```

EDIT: I used the response below and am now getting the error as depicted in my image below...
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJ32.png)

The sideways image on the left should be next to the table. Not above and to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your table inside another table like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Put Your Image Here</td>
    <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>      
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>        
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>        
            <td>80</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/rgangdan/

Comment: This somewhat works...

Now my new image I added in the new table is on top of the current table pushing the current table down. I added a screenshot in my original post to show what I mean.

Comment: Could you link to your new code or make a fiddle? It's hard to tell what's not working with just an image.

Comment: Actually I just got it to work. Just some syntax error. The issue I am having now is that since there is now a new table nesting my old table the original table is slightly off-center to the right. Do I just need to manually adjust where it is on the page using padding?

Comment: That should do it if you have the power. I assume it's the width of the image pushing it over to the right.